# Javascript getElementById("string").value for HTML form input

Tags: javascript, input, getelementbyid

I want to add the user input values for rounds 1 and 2 when you press the calculate button but it's not retrieving the values of the input fields i'm "getting by id".

My script.js doc is linked to at the bottom of the html document already.
I've made some updates to the JS.

https://jsfiddle.net/f7p0swpk/2/

```
var roundOne = document.getElementById("roundOne").value;
var roundTwo = document.getElementById("roundTwo").value;

function add() {
    var total = roundOne + roundTwo;
    document.querySelector(".total").textContent = total;
}
```

Comment: The values read from DOM are string and `+` will act as string concatenation operator. Convert the strings to Numbers. Not just that, you're using `return` in `add()`. It should be `var`. The code should run when the DOM is ready, either wrap code in `DOMContentLoaded` or move the `<script>` to the end of `<body>`. [**Working Code**](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f7p0swpk/1/) note that in fiddle, I've selected `No Wrap - <body>` option to load script.

Comment: I don't think integer conversion is needed

Comment: Got it. You are returning from the first line of method before calculating

Comment: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/f7p0swpk/7/) try